# Activate $httpMock after angular app has been initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpbackend

I want to be able to turn on and off a $httpBackend mock in my angularJS app.

That means I want to inject the $httpBackend lazily/on demand.
It would also be nice to be able to turn it on and off again.

For example to provide input data for an AngularJS app that is being previewed from a CMS.

The below code does only work if I move the ngMockE2E to an ordinary dependency, and inject $httpBackend to my factory the standard way.

The code sets upp $httpBackend on all calls from a config file, and then responds to all of them...

```
const registerCalls = () => {
    const injectormock = angular.injector(['ngMockE2E']); //lazy load not working as expected
    const $httpBackend = injectormock.get('$httpBackend'); //lazy load not working as expected.
    //Pass through for resources:
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*.html/).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*.json/).passThrough();
    //API calls should be mocked:
    const apiCalls = {};
    for (var call in apiConfig) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(apiConfig, call)) {
            const callConfig = apiConfig[call];
            const url = angular.isDefined(callConfig.regex) ? callConfig.regex : callConfig.url();
            if (callConfig.method === 'GET') {
                apiCalls[call] = $httpBackend.whenGET(url);
            } else if (callConfig.method === 'POST') {
                apiCalls[call] = $httpBackend.whenPOST(url);
            }
        }
    }
    return apiCalls;

}

const success = function() {
    const apiCalls = registerCalls();
    for (var call in apiConfig) {
        let response = {};
        if (angular.isDefined(apiConfig[call].response)) {
            response = apiConfig[call].response();
        }
        apiCalls[call].respond(200, response);
    }
};
```

How can I setup the $httpBackend so that it can be activated/deactivated while the AngularJS app is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular services are singletons that are lazily instantiated on first injection. If the injection of `$httpBackend` is performed on application bootstrap (which is usually the case when `$http` is used), it's not possible to mock a service.

Getting E2E `$httpBackend` version through `angular.injector` is obvious but wrong way to do this. This will result in having new injector instance that uses its own core service singletons (`$browser`, etc).

The clean way to do this is through `angular.mock.e2e` global, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42331623/3731501). It will be available [once angular-mocks.js is loaded](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.4/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2426). The point is to decorate `$httpBackend` (which is a function) to wrap both original and E2E implementations and use them conditionally.

It can be done like that:

```
angular.module('mockableHttp', [])
.decorator('$httpBackend', function ($injector, $delegate) {
  var $httpBackendOriginal = $delegate;
  var $httpBackendE2E = $injector.invoke(angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator, null, {
    $delegate: $delegate
  });

  function $httpBackend() {
    var $httpBackendImplementation = $httpBackend.isMocking
      ? $httpBackendE2E
      : $httpBackendOriginal;

    return $httpBackendImplementation.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return Object.assign($httpBackend, $httpBackendE2E, {
    enableMocking: function() {
      $httpBackend.isMocking = true;
    },
    disableMocking: function() {
      $httpBackend.isMocking = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Where `mockableHttp` is loaded in app module (can be totally excluded in production) and HTTP mocks are activated with `$httpBackend.enableMocking()`.