# Angular Jasmine Integration Test with service using real HTTP

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, integration-testing

[Angular version: 2.4.5]

I'm attempting to write an Angular integration component unit test that contains a service that leverages the built-in Angular HTTP library.  I cannot get my Service class to instantiate though: either the Service is undefined or I get "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RequestOptions'(?)".

I understand that typically you'd mock the backend (have successfully done that in other unit tests) or use Protractor. Other SO questions reference Angular 1 or have answers that just don't seem to work.  Starting code:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ProjectService {
        projectFeature: IProjectFeature;

        constructor(private http: Http) { }

        getProjects(): Observable<IProjects> {
        return this.http.get("/api/Projects")
            .map((response: Response) => response.json() || {})
            .catch(this.handleError);
         }
    }

     // Jasmine spec file:   
        beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                Http,
                ProjectService,  // service that leverages HTTP
                ConnectionBackend
                //RequestOptions  // removed b/c otherwise can't find parameters error happens
            ],
            imports: [
               HttpModule
            ] 
        });
    }));

    it('sample test', async(() => {
        var projectService = TestBed.get(ProjectService);
        var comp = new ProjectComponent(projectService);
        comp.ngOnInit();  // internally, calls projectService.getProjects()
        expect(comp.projects[0].name).toEqual("Sample Project Name");
    }));
```

Comment: You didn't supply HttpModule to TestBed, have you?

Comment: @estus not currently. I've added it, and updated the code above.  Now it fails, saying "can't read property Response of undefined"

Comment: It's not possible to say what's wrong in your case. Considering that this is integration test, there may be much more code than you've posted. Any way, it is as simple as that (much simpler than [it was in A1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42331623/3731501)). I've added the answer that illustrates how it's done.

Comment: Did the answer work out for you? If it did, consider accepting it or providing some feedback otherwise, this will help future SO visitors.

Comment: Apologies @estus! Still had difficulties, causing me to rethink my testing strategy for a bit, then I went on vacation, haha. Accepted! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpModule` module should be provided in `TestBed` module configuration. After that, `Http` performs real XHR requests, no extra actions needed, a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9xEB6myPEtXMmLYMXpHu?p=preview):

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();

    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ]
    });

  });

  it('should do XHR', async(inject([Http], (http) => {
    http.get('test.json').subscribe(res => {
      expect(res.json()).toBe(1);
    });
  })));
```