# Using Jasmine to test an Angular Service that loads a static JSON file

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have been slightly diverging from the guidance in [Testing Services in Angular 2](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-services-in-angular-2) to test this method, `loadIndex()`:

```
loadIndex(): Promise<Response> {
    this.index = null;
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.isLoading = true;

    const promise = this.client
        .get('./src/assets/data/index.json') // TODO: inject this from config?
        .toPromise();
    promise
        .catch(() => {
            this.isError = true;
            this.isLoaded = false;
        })
        .then(responseOrVoid => {
            const response = <Response>responseOrVoid;
            if (!response) {
                return;
            }

            this.index = response.json().data as Array<BlogEntry>;
            if (!this.index) {
                return;
            }

            this.isLoaded = true;
            this.isLoading = false;
        });

    return promise;
}
```

with this test:

```
import { TestBed, async, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BaseRequestOptions,
    Http,
    Response,
    ResponseOptions,
    XHRBackend
} from '@angular/http';
import { BlogEntriesService } from './songhay-blog-entries.service';
import { BlogEntry } from '../models/songhay-blog-entry';
import { error } from 'util';

describe('BlogEntriesService', () => {
    const testBed = getTestBed();
    let service: BlogEntriesService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                BaseRequestOptions,
                BlogEntriesService,
                {
                    deps: [BaseRequestOptions],
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (
                        backend: XHRBackend,
                        defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions
                    ) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions)
                }
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should load index', done => {
        service = testBed.get(BlogEntriesService);
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
        service
            .loadIndex()
            .then(result => {
                expect(result).toBeDefined();
            })
            .catch(result => expect(result).toBeUndefined())
            .then(done);
    });
});
```

I have removed the `MockBackend` code from my test because I think I do not need it because I am loading a local, static JSON file (not really a *unit* test). So the error I am getting is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of undefined

at mergeOptions (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js:1824:1)
    at Http.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Http.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js:1924:1)
    at BlogEntriesService.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/services/songhay-blog-entries.service.ts.BlogEntriesService.loadIndex (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/src/app/services/songhay-blog-entries.service.ts:78:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/src/app/services/songhay-blog-entries.service.spec.ts:39:14)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/../angular.io-index-app/index-app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:1)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?da99c5b057693d025fad3d7685e1590600ca376d:3945:24)
```

Is this issue here known? Should I just give up and build an e2e test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has DI problems. `Http` factory has one dependency injected:

```
deps: [BaseRequestOptions],
```

While the factory expects 2 parameters, and they are mixed up.

Instead, it should be:

```
{
    deps: [XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (
        backend: XHRBackend,
        defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions
    ) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions)
}
```

The only reason why `Http` provider is defined this way is that because usually the backend is replaced with `MockBackend` in unit tests. If this is not the case for integration test, [`HttpModule` can be just imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641478/angular-jasmine-integration-test-with-service-using-real-http) instead.

Comment: the corrected test is here: https://github.com/BryanWilhite/angular.io-index-app/blob/master/index-app/src/app/services/songhay-blog-entries.service.spec.ts

Comment: Http provider is redundant and can be omitted if If HttpModule has been imported.

Comment: I'll take a look at the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9xEB6myPEtXMmLYMXpHu?p=preview) you recommended and work my way toward my scenario as simply removing references to `Http` breaks things in ways I currently do not understand.